# Do milk and orange juice contain H2O molecules?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm asking as there is this woman who claims she's severely allergic to (you guessed it) water (H2O molecules). She says just a drop of water in her mouth sends her into anaphylactic shock and only adrenaline reverses this.

Now how's this relevant to this question? She says she survives on milk and orange juice, which ''because of their chemical composition'' bring her no harm. She's basically saying orange juice and milk are something 100% separate from water and don't contain free H2O molecules in them.

Comment: Here is some science for your own curiosity (full disclosure, it was my question) https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7905/what-is-the-smallest-molecule-that-can-present-as-an-antigen-to-the-immune-syste, but the direct answer to your question is that both contain significant amounts of water.

Comment: Off topic but lot of people say they are allergic to things just to call attention...might be particular of our times...

Comment: Most of the weight of a human body is water. Anyone allergic to water would die instantly. This sort of malarkey is why STEM education is necessary.

Comment: There is such a thing as "water allergy" but it's only a problem for getting water on your skin, not drinking it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquagenic_urticaria

Comment: @DSVA I'd just use quotations for the "allergy" bit (since it isn't technically an allergy) ;-) Great find by the way!

Comment: This popped up again. Besides some contaminate in water, I'd wonder if pure water on skin could allow some bacteria, fungus, or mold to thrive on the skin. So the biological contaminant is dormant when dry, but quickly becomes active when moist.

Answer (score 2):

Both orange juice and milk are approx. 88% water, just like many other foods. The human body is about 60% water as well.

Therefore, she must be allergic to something her tap water contains other than water, such as chlorate from water treatment or some other contaminant which is not contained in orange juice or milk, assuming what is claimed is a fact and not just her imagination.

The solution is to install a good water filter in her faucet or drink bottled water in case there actually is some allergen in the tap water. In the worse case, she can try a drop of distilled water (which is pure water) just to confirm experimentally as well that it is not H2O that is the issue. Note: Drinking distilled water regularly is sometimes said to cause health problems as in the long term it deprives the body of minerals; see, for example, https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/317698.php and https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=28557. However, this is a controversial topic.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Edited accordingly, i have softened up the distilled water story as well as i made it sound more serious than it actually is.

Comment: We should not give medical advice here. The woman needs to see a doctor. What kind is the only question. The OP should not under any circumstances do medical experiments with her.

Comment: @MaxW Good point, sorted.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquagenic_urticaria technically it's not an allergy but it seems like it actually is the water and not something in it. But afaik these people do not have problems drinking water since you don't got skin inside of you.

Comment: Had a look too and, believe it or not, this is actually a thing indeed: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5438944/ Very controversial however and i am really not convinced: so you can bath in orange juice but not water? Rules out UK as a habitat then. Also, not a medical journal expert but the journals i found this published in seem very weak.